# Using LDAP in Java GWT, working on localhost but not on the server -> errorcode 34

Tags: java, gwt, ldap

I'm making an application with java GWT where LDAP is used to retrieve a bunch of data. 
Everything is working fine on localhost, but once I upload everyting to our server, LDAP keeps giving me errorcode 34. I've done some research, and it's an InvalidNameException. Looking at the loggs, i get this;

```
LDAP: error code 34 - 0000208F: NameErr: DSID-031001F7, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8350, best   match of:
'ldap:,OU=FMP-FBZ'
```

So apparently I am not giving a valid name. This is strange becuase on localhost everything works fine!

**edit:**
I do notice that there is a comma (,) right after 'ldap: in the codeline above, i'm guessing that might be the cause, but that would mean that somehow somewhere a piece of code gets removed or altered on the server....

This is my method retrieving all the data;

```
private final String PROVIDER_URL = "ldap://xxx/OU=FMP-FBZ Users, DC=xxx ,DC=xxx, DC=xxx";
private final String PROVIDER_URL_VDI = "ldap://xxx/OU=FMP-FBZ Users VDI, DC= xxx, DC=xxx, DC=xxx";

    DirContext ctx = null;
    NamingEnumeration results = null;
    HashSet<String> LDAPloginNames = new HashSet<String>();

    PROVIDER_URLS.add(PROVIDER_URL);
    PROVIDER_URLS.add(PROVIDER_URL_VDI);

    for (String URL : PROVIDER_URLS) {
        try {
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, URL);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=xxx,CN=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "xxx");

            ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

            SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
            controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            results = ctx.search(PROVIDER_URL, "(objectClass=person)", controls);
            while (results.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) results.next();
                Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();

                if(attributes.get("mail")!= null) {
                    LDAPloginNames.add(attributes.get("name").get().toString());
                }
            }

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (results != null) {
                try {
                    results.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            if (ctx != null) {
                try {
                    ctx.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return new ArrayList<String>(LDAPloginNames);
```

As you can see, I am using 2 urls, could that be causing any trouble? If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great! 
Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at the same LDAP locally as from the server? You might have to trim() and clean characters like the comma you mention but, yes, it's curious why that wouldn't matter locally.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by _"looking at the same LDAP locally as from the server"_, but I am looking at the same directories on the server yes. I don't think trimming will matter much because the originel statement contains multiple comma's. You know you're screwed when even SO can't find an answer, hehe. Thnx for the suggestions though!